# Brute force for derivation of all possible matrices in R

Tags: r

Let `H` a matrix with dimension `KxN`. The elements of `H` can be `0` and `1`. Then I would like to create all possible matrices with dimensions `KxN` whose elements are only `0` and `1` with the use of brute force.

For example, if

```
K=2
N=2
H = matrix(c(1,1,1,1),N,K,byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
```

the matrix `H` has dimensions `2x2`, hence, all the possible matrices with dimension `2x2` and elements only `0` and `1` are the following:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    0

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    0    1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    0    0

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    0
```

Ideally I would like to find a brute force way that can be used for every possible dimension `KxN` of matrix `H`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid`.

```
K <- 2
N <- 2
lapply(asplit(do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(0:1), K*N)), 1), matrix, N, K)
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    0    0
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    0
#
#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    1    0
#
#[[4]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    1    0
#
#[[5]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    0    0
#
#[[6]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    0    0
#
#[[7]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    1    0
#
#[[8]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    0
#
#[[9]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    0    1
#
#[[10]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1
#
#[[11]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    1    1
#
#[[12]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    1    1
#
#[[13]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    0    1
#
#[[14]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    0    1
#
#[[15]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    1
#[2,]    1    1
#
#[[16]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! With the approached that I was trying, I had a bunch of nested LOOPS

Comment: @Jonathan1234 With `N == 20` and `K == 2`, I get *"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4096.0 Gb"*.

Answer (score 1):

Though there already is an accepted answer, here is another one, using package [`arrangements`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=arrangements).

```
allBinMat <- function(nrow, ncol, byrow = TRUE){
  if(!require(arrangements)){
    stop("there is no package called 'arrangements'.")
  }
  x <- permutations(0:1, nrow*ncol, replace = TRUE, layout = "list")
  lapply(x, matrix, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, byrow = byrow)
}

allBinMat(2, 2)
allBinMat(2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your function works, perfect! Should I try to add a question here in the comment or start a new post about how to handle SVD computations to this enormous list of matrices for large ```N``` and ```K```?

Comment: @Jonathan1234 `lapply(H, svd)` would work. But for *large*  `N` and `K` the function above wouldn't, it throws an error even for modest sizes. Too many permutations.